# Как загрузить готовое Android-приложение (файл .apk) в эмулируемую среду в Visual Studio, чтобы оно там было изначально?

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Мне нужно создавать автоматизированные тесты для Android-приложения в Visual Studio при помощи Xamarin.UITest. Тестировать надо уже созданное приложение, которое в виде файла .apk.
Как сделать, чтобы при запуске теста и загрузке эмулятора-Android, это приложение уже было там.
Я читал о том, что можно просто перетащить файл .apk на экран эмулятора, но тогда это придется делать каждый раз.
Как автоматизировать этот процесс?

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://youtu.be/cMP5H-dZj3E?t=600) начиная с 10 мин. показывают как прописать путь к apk, чтоб при тестировании он автоматом копировался. Это то, что вам надо?

Comment: Скорее всего да, попробую. Большое спасибо!